# How to auto click on a radio button if a determined image is loaded on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's two radio buttons on the page, one for "Yes" and another one for "No". I have no experience with jQuery, javascript or html, but I need to create some script/code to auto click on one of those buttons according with the image src that is loaded on the page.

So, if the image src on the page is "a.jpg", it will auto click always on the "Yes" radio button, and if it's "b.jpg" will always click on the "No" radio button.

Comment: can you please share some of the code you've written? such as the HTML and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

First, write a conditional for what you want to check based on img src

Then to check it: `$('input').attr('checked', true)`

If you need more help post the HTML/JS that you have so far

---

You could do something like this using jQuery:

```
var imageSrc = $('img').attr('src');
if(imageSrc === 'http://localhost/mysite/a.jpg'){
  $('.true').attr('checked', true);
}else{
  $('.false').attr('checked', true);
}
```

Note you would have to set the class name of the inputs as well.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input type="radio" class="form-check-input true" value="true"><label class="form-check-label">Yes</label></div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input type="radio" class="form-check-input false" value="false"><label class="form-check-label">No</label></div>

<img src="http://localhost/mysite/a.jpg" class="d-none">
```

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery too

```
$('img[src="YourImgSrc"]').on('load',function(){
     $('#YourRadioId').prop("checked",true);
});
```